# Avoiding python ints being truncated to 32 bits when sent through a Qt signal-slot connection

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-signals

### Issue

I have some `QObject`s living on different threads that communicate using Qt Signals and Slots. I'm using *PyQt5* (through *qtpy*), but I don't think it's specific to that API or version.

One of the values being sent is an integer on the order of 2^40, but as the C++ type `int` is only 32 bits wide, this is silently being truncated.

I've replaced the Signal&Slot types with `'long'`, but that only works on some machines (see results below), so I've fallen back on wrapping the value in a 1-element tuple, as Qt will pass Python objects on unmodified.

### Testcase

```py
from qtpy import QtCore
                                                                                                                      
class Sender(QtCore.QObject):                                                                                         
    intsig = QtCore.Signal(int)                                                                                       
    longsig = QtCore.Signal('long')
    tuplesig = QtCore.Signal(tuple)                                                                                   
    done = QtCore.Signal()                                                                                            
        
    def __init__(self, thread):
        super().__init__()                                                                                            
        self.moveToThread(thread)                                                                                     
        thread.started.connect(self.start)                                                                            
        self.done.connect(thread.quit)                                                                                
        
    def start(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.send)                                                                     
        
    def send(self, value=123456789012345):                                                                            
        self.intsig.emit(value)                                                                                      
        self.tuplesig.emit((value,))                                                                                       
        self.longsig.emit(value)                                                                                  
        self.done.emit()                                                                                              
        
class Receiver(QtCore.QObject):                                                                                       
        
    def __init__(self, thread):
        super().__init__()                                                                                            
        self.moveToThread(thread)                                                                                     
        
    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def intslot(self, val):                                                                                           
        print(f"intslot: {val}")                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
    @QtCore.Slot('long') 
    def longslot(self, val):                                                                                          
        print(f"longslot: {val}")
                
    @QtCore.Slot(tuple)                                                                                               
    def tupleslot(self, val):
        print(f"tupleslot: {val[0]}")                                                                                 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                            
    qa = QtCore.QCoreApplication(['foo'])                                                                             
    sthread = QtCore.QThread()                                                                                        
    rthread = QtCore.QThread()
    sender = Sender(sthread)
    receiver = Receiver(rthread)
    sender.intsig.connect(receiver.intslot)                                                                           
    sender.longsig.connect(receiver.longslot)                                                                         
    sender.tuplesig.connect(receiver.tupleslot)                                                                       
    sthread.finished.connect(rthread.quit)                                                                            
    rthread.finished.connect(qa.quit)                                                                                 

    rthread.start()                                                                                                   
    sthread.start() 
    qa.exec()
    sthread.wait()
    rthread.wait()
```

### Results

Result on my development machine (Gentoo Linux (updated in March 2023), amd64):

```
$ python3.8 --version && python3.8 -m test
Python 3.8.16
intslot: -2045911175
tupleslot: 123456789012345
longslot: 123456789012345
$ python3.9 --version && python3.9 -m test
Python 3.9.16
intslot: -2045911175
tupleslot: 123456789012345
longslot: 123456789012345
$ python3.10 --version && python3.10 -m test
Python 3.10.10
intslot: -2045911175
tupleslot: 123456789012345
longslot: 123456789012345
```

Result on the target machine (Raspberry Pi OS (based on Debian 11.6), RPi 4 Model B Rev 1.4, armv7l):

```
$ python --version && python -m test
Python 3.9.2
intslot: -2045911175
tupleslot: 123456789012345
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 21, in send
    self.longsig.emit(value)
TypeError: Sender.longsig[long].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
Aborted
```

### Question

Am I missing something with regard to coercing python primitives to the right C++ types? Or is the type mapping subtly architecture-/machine-/version-dependent? Is wrapping things that might not fit in the basic C++ types in python objects the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Not a Qt expert, but if long isn't long enough, how about long long?

Comment: Long is long enough, but on a raspberry pi, for some reason, trying to emit a 'long' type signal with an int value, raises a TypeError.

Comment: Huh. Maybe you've got a different underlying Qt library under the QtPy abstraction layer on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: PyQt5-5.15.2 on the pi, PyQt5-5.15.6 on my dev machine.

Comment: Using `object` as signature type should avoid any conversion issues. Also, remove the slot decorators.

Comment: `object` is a cleaner way to do essentially the same thing as my `tuple` method, but I'd like to figure out how to properly use native C++ types. Why should I remove the slot decorators? As far as I can tell, they're useful in some cases, and never actively harmful.

Comment: @AI0867 You can't always use native C++ types because python doesn't support all of them and PyQt/PySide do automatic type conversions when switching between the C++ and Python sides. Besides, since you don't seem to need those signals to directly connect to C++ slots, there would be very little point in attempting to use those types: in fact, using `object` is theoretically better and faster, since there would be no conversion at all. Slot decorators are useful in *some* cases: they may be required when using QML or while developing Designer plugins, and may provide *some* slight ->

Comment: @AI0867 -> performance improvement, but only in case you have *lots* of slots (in the order of hundreds). They could also be necessary for signal overloads, but in the latest years Qt has been gradually removing any signal overload, so that makes it even less necessary. For any other case, they are actually unnecessary. (please use `@username` when replying to a comment and other users are participating to a conversation)

Comment: @AI0867 What was the compiler used to build the RPI OS? Is it in the list of [officially supported platforms](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html)? If so, that would seem to imply [qint64](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qint64-typedef) should work (i.e. `QtCore.Signal('qint64')`). However, I really don't see the point of any of this, since you'll only ever see a python int in your code, no matter what you do. Why do you care what Qt does with the value? If you're fussy about documenting the type, just create your own `bigint` subclass (which will have no limit at all).

Comment: @ekhumoro I do intend to use modules implemented in C, C++ or rust at some point, so the actual type will be relevant at some point. As for the RPi OS, that's whatever was available from the official website.

Comment: @AI0867 Okay - so what specific compiler is it? And did you try `qint64`?

Comment: You already know the answer and seem to be asking an opinion. This does not fit on SO. Anyway, here's my opinion. As you already know, this is dependent on the implementation of the binding library(PySide2, PySide6, PyQt5, PyQt6, etc.) and of course that implementation works differently on different platforms(32bit/64bit OS, Windows, Linux, X86, ARM, etc.). Even Qt itself works differently on different platforms.

Comment: @ekhumoro `qint64` indeed seems to work on both platforms. I don't see why `long` causes issues, but I now know 2 working approaches (`object` and `qint64`). I have no idea which compiler is used for compiling the binaries of RPi OS.

Comment: @relent95 I've repeatedly had serious trouble finding more than superficial documentation for python/qt bindings, so I was hoping for a more detailed explanation of what's going on and how to work with the system rather than against it. I'll rewrite the question a bit to that effect, and possibly add an answer with what worked for me, but leave it open for a few more days in case someone wants to provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: @AI0867 There is not a lot of documentation because 99% of the Python/Qt developers only use Python, are not really interested in the underlying aspects, and the official C++ API documentation is quite sufficient. For future reference, remember to explain the context of your question: if you mentioned that you already knew about using `object` and that you needed to know more because you intend to interface with other languages, the scope of your post would have been more clear since the beginning. Also, consider writing to the PyQt mailing list.

Comment: @musicamante At the time, I hadn't thought of using `object`, or I wouldn't have used `tuple` as a workaround.

Comment: @AI0867 It causes issues for the simple reason that in the C/C++ standards the size of a `long` does not have a fixed size. It is only required to be a *minimum* of 32 bits, so it may vary between implementations. That is the whole point of Qt's `qint64` typedef: it is guaranteed to be same size on all supported platforms.

Comment: @ekhumoro True, but I'm not communicating between platforms, so while I expected possible problems like "long is only 32 bits on some machine, so it still gets truncated there", but not "trying to send a python int as a long raises a TypeError".

Comment: @AI0867 I neither said, not implied, that you were *communicating* between platforms. If you want the same code to behave the same way on different platforms, you should either use a fixed-sized type (e.g. `qint64`), or an unbounded type (e.g. `object`). However, no matter what *Qt/C++* type you use, if you send a value outside its defined range, you will get that same type-error. Arguably, it should be a value-error instead - but whatever, it makes no odds really. If you don't agree with that behaviour, raise an issue on the [mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/).

Comment: @AI0867 I think you may be confused about the difference between maximum *size* and maximum *value*. A `long` is signed, so the absolute value of its minimum/maximum is roughly half its range. Values exceeding the minimum/maximum will overflow until they exceed the entire range, at which point they will cause an error (because they are too big to fit into the allocated space).